# Custom Validation returns "Method [validateAlphaSpace] does not exist" in Laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I am trying to register new custom validation but get this error:

> Method [validateAlphaSpace] does not exist. [Laravel 5]

Here is my code:

CustomValidator.php

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
class CustomValidator extends Validator {

    public function alpha_space($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/u', $value);
    }

}
```

ValidatorServicePorvider.php

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\CustomValidator;
class ValidatorServicePorvider extends ServiceProvider {

 /**
  * Bootstrap any necessary services.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function boot()
 {

     Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
                        {
                            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
                        });
 }

 /**
  * Register the service provider.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function register()
 {

 }

}
```

I also register provider inside app.php... Anyone can see what is problem?

Comment: the error already told you what is going on,

you have to change your method name of "alpha_space" to "validateAlphaSpace"

that is the laravel way to add custom validation

Comment: you might want to take look at [Custom Validation Rules](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method in the custom validator class must be prefixed with "validate". In your case, try by renaming `alpha_space` method into `validateAlphaSpace`.